# Ember.js afterModel hook triggers two identical requests

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

in my app I need that when I visit the root, it redirects to the view of the most recent model that in this case is always the firstObject in the collection.

```
App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('threads', { path: '/' }, function() {
        this.route('view', { path: ':thread_id' });
    });
});

App.ThreadsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.find('thread');
  },
  afterModel: function(threads) {
    this.transitionTo('threads.view', threads.get('firstObject'));
  }
});
```

This is working without problems, but wheter I directly go to the root url or the view one 2 identical requests to `/threads` are made. As soon I comment the `afterModel` section the redirection obviously doesn't work anymore but the requests are back to 1.

Any help is gladly accepted!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Threads/View are nested routes, the ThreadsRoute will be also called on the View route.

I think you should just call the ThreadsRoute -> ThreadsIndexRoute or separate model and afterModel hooks this way:

(Not tested code)

```
App.ThreadsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    // console.log('in model);
    return this.store.find('thread');
  }
});

App.ThreadsIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  afterModel: function(threads) {
   // console.log('in afterModel);
    this.transitionTo('threads.view', threads.get('firstObject'));
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Your example is identical to this one:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('threads', { path: '/' }, function() {
        this.route('view', { path: ':thread_id' });
    });
});

App.ThreadsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.find('thread');
  }
});

App.ThreadsIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.find('thread');
  }
});
```

If you check the inspector for which route you're in when you visit `'/'`, you'll see that you're inside of 
`threads.index`, having transitioned into each of them in turn, which is why you're seeing the call to find twice.
You can fix this by only having the model hook in `ThreadsIndexRoute` (e.g. rename your `ThreadsRoute` to `ThreadsIndexRoute`)

Comment: Ok, that's reasonale. So I need to override that but in which way considering that its behaviour must remain the same? Also seems that with the latest ember version the parent model will be passet to the children routes http://emberjs.com/blog/2014/03/30/ember-1-5-0-and-ember-1-6-beta-released.html#toc_routes-inherit-model

Comment: Moreover if I pass an instance of a model into `transitionTo` it should not trigger the model hook. Look at the bottom of the first section of this page http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/redirection/